# Server side handling of PDF submitted with attachments (XDP/XML/PDF)

Tags: c#, xml, pdf, server, livecycle

I have PDF forms, that clients fill out and submit. Functionalities designed with LiveCycle, submitted to server as XML. The server side application is coded in C#, it reads and processes the XML content.

I need to add the capability that users can attach a document or two (word files, images) to the PDFs and then submit. The PDFs will have User Rights, users will be able to save filled out contents and accept attachments even with a Reader.
Can this be done?

I think I'll have to use submission as an Xml Data Package. But I'm not sure if it would still be possible to send attachments to the server along with the PDF content.

Please advise me on whether this can be done? If yes, then what type of submission should I use (XDP / XML /PDF)? and how should I read / handle / extract attachments on the server side once the data is received via HTTP.

As of now I'm using StreamReader to read the XML data received via HTTP request.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this a web service that clients are calling to upload files? Do you want clients to upload the PDF with the attachments in one action or is multiple uploads acceptable? XDP can't/isn't designed to handle random file types. If the additional files are going to be attachments in the PDF then why not just have the clients upload the PDF with the attachments already in the PDF?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Clients download the dynamic PDF from a website. Fill it out and submit. Its submitted as XML data to a URL. The server side app processes the XML received, mails it forward appropriately. I want clients to attach 1 or two documents to the PDF and press the submit button as usual. I want the server application to be able to receive and render the attachments.

Comment: I think then you could use either XDP or PDF as the format clients upload to your application. If the user is attaching files to the PDF and then submitting to your application then your application just needs to know how to handle PDF/XDP. PDF submissions might be slightly easier to deal with on the server side as most PDF SDKs understand attachments. With XDP you would most likely have to convert it to a real PDF before being able to get the attachments out of the PDF.